# Moving some commits to a feature branch but leaving others in the master branch

Tags: tortoisegit

I am not sure if I can do anything about this and it is not a huge hardship to leave it as it is.

I did try to fix things by following steps on other SO topics etc. and ended up loosing all my help revision commits and files.

Things are a little messy and I will try to explain. The history is OK up to a certain point:

> Removing unused resource ID values from resource.h

Can you see that towards the bottom of the screenshot of the log?

[image: Help Topics - Show Log]

Since that time, the majority of the commits are help file revisions:

- Deleting help topics and redundant images
- Revising help topics and images
- Adding new help topics and images

But it gets complicated because with that big chunk of help revision commits I have some code change commits. Eg:

> Added SetLoggingPath to CMSATools.
>
> Revised CChristianLifeMinistryUtils::FillStudentsListBox method. Now it reads the students from the publishers database.

The plot thickens, for a small handful of them, eg:

> Add Help menu to CPublishersDatabaseDlg.

In those cases the commit is a combination of code changes and help revision changes:

> Added OnHelpHelp menu handler.
>
> Started writing Help/HelpPublisherDatabase.html help topic.

The primary issue:

Beginning at this commit in the master branch: **Removing unused resource ID values from resource.h** can I make a new feature branch called: **help-revisions** and then, **move** the commits from master to the feature branch?

If it is possible, I am assuming we would need to move just the commits that are purely help revisions. I am not sure how to handle the commits that are a mixture of help changes and code changes.

So, ideally I am hoping to split out all the help revisions into a feature branch so that it can be merged in to the master and look better in the log. Leaving the code tweak commits alone in the master in an appropriate position.

The related matter is the **cause** of some of this. But I am not going to discuss that here after all.

As mentioned, I am just curious as to know if it is possible to improve the history I have as indicated.

I am a lone developer so do not have to worry about other individuals repositories.

Thanks for your help and time.

### Update

I have given the rebase a go. I marked all the commits I wanted to split as edit. Then I started the rebase. I ticked edit/split and revised them as I needed until it completed.

Now my log looks like this:

[image: Log]

Underneath, it looks like this:

[image: Log]

So how do I get rid of that section? I have to fix that before I create the feature branch and do the cherry picking.

So, at the top I now have a new set of all the commits including the split ones.

Got it - did a force push of master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by a mixture of cherry-picking and rebasing.

1. Create a new feature branch which is before all your commits which are affected. Then select all commits you want to have on that new feature branch and select "Cherry-pick commits". After that you have a branch where only the selected commits are on.
2. Switch back to the previous branch and do a rebase on the parent of the newly created branch (you will need to enabled "force"). Now mark all cherry-picked commits again and select skip and start the rebase. Now, this branch does not contain the cherry-picked branches any more.

Comment: So for step one I create a branch and select it as active. Then from the log select commits and choose cherry pick to duplicate them into the branch. Right? But, you reckon I should leave the commits that are a mixture of help and code changes?

Comment: Yes, the cherry-pick is to duplicate/rescue the commits. The mixture will be gone after the rebase as were dropping them there.

Comment: Yes. I will try tomorrow. So just to clarify, there are three types of commits. 1. Those to stay in master. 2. Those to cherry pick to feature branch. 3. Those which are a bit of both and technically bits fall in both branches.

Comment: You do only one rebase operation. If you have commits which fit on both branches, why forcibly use a feature branch?

Comment: Well, it is not that they fit both. It is that they should be split. I shouldn't have done one commit with both a code change and also help changes. I could always delete those commits. There are not many and perhaps redo.

Comment: Splitting commits is also possible using the rebase dialog (maybe that would be the first step then, mark all commits you want to split as "Edit" and then you can select "Split/Edit commit" to split it by deselecting some changes for one commit. - Btw. I would not split code and help changes as those are often logically dependent.

Comment: I have a case where I do want to split. I can't work out how to mark a commit as edit.

Comment: On the rebase dialog right click on the commit and select "Edit".

Comment: OK, I made progress. I gave it a go. But, I am a little confused with the results - nearly there. :) I will update question again right now.

Comment: That's the old remote branch, force push your master branch and the "duplicate" section is gone.