# Changes to TortoiseGit log

Tags: tortoisegit

Here is top of my log:

[image: Log]

I had merged a branch and have changed my mind. I know it is only cosmetic but I want it to look like a U shape on the flow chart. Not a continuous line. And I no longer have the actual branch to play with.

What I would like to do is:

1. Edit the commit shown in green. It should say v17.1.1 !
2. Move the 3 magenta ones into a U shaped branch on the log.

Can I do this?

Thank you.

## Update

I have messed up a bit it seems:

[image: Updated log]

## Update 2

If I switch off the master-temp branch (that was copied at the existing HEAD before the rebase) it looks like this:

[image: Updated log]

Not quite how I wanted.

## Update 3

Managed to follow this:

[Correctly merging a feature branch using TortoiseGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794529/correctly-merging-a-feature-branch-using-tortoisegit)

I am happy now:

[image: Updated log]

Comment: Yes it's possible. Use the steps as described in http://stackoverflow.com/q/42191902/3906760.

Comment: As I already pointed out, a branch is just a label to a comment, you can easily right on a commit and create a new branch there. It's also recommended to create a branch on the current HEAD before doing rebasing, so that all commits are not "lost" and easily reachable using a temporary branch.

Comment: @MrTux Thanks for that link. Managed to do some of what you said, but it doesn't look quite right. Please see updated screen shot.

Comment: @MrTux Relatest question though - see the "Sing Joyfully To Jehovah ..."  It should be "Sing Out Joyfully To Jehovah ... ". I understand about using Rebase and force and right-clicking a commit and putting "Edit". But this will not edit it in place. I just wish we could fix mistakes with commits in the history simply rather than a complex methodology.

Comment: Editing a commit message is not easily possible as this alters history - it's a rebase operation.